# The problem of flutter internationalization

Tags: flutter, intl

My current main project is called A, which relies on a local package B,

B’s internationalization is invalid and always returns to the default value. The flutter_intl plugin is used. This is my issue: https://github.com/localizely/flutter-intl-intellij/issues/50

I hope my description is clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer:
https://zhuoyuan.blog.csdn.net/article/details/111176805

change l10n.dart code.